# Why cordova build android error?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Why run the command cordova build android ,error every time

exe: cordova build android

**sample CMD:** 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
  >   Searched Location:
  >   C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\lottery-thailand\platforms\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  >   C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\lottery-thailand\platforms\android\app\google-services.json
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
18 actionable tasks: 18 executed
(node:20776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a plugin which takes advantage of one or more Google services but you are missing your info file.

For these to build and work properly you need to include the Google services info file (`google-services.json` for Android and/or `GoogleService-Info.plist` for iOS) in the root of your project. Check to make sure the file is there, if it is not then you will need to download it from the service you are using and place it in the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I find similar error upgrading to phonegap `7.0.0` from `6.3.0` using `cordova-plugin-fcm`. I solved editing line 58 of `fcm_config_files_process.js` in `\plugins\cordova-plugin-fcm\scripts.js`

From

```
fs.writeFileSync("platforms/android/google-services.json", contents);
```

To

```
fs.writeFileSync("platforms/android/app/google-services.json", contents);
```